# Add sub collection as part of a single ID document Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to save the urls of multiple images (previously loaded in Storage) in a subcollection of a firestore document.

So far I have achieved it but it generates a document (with its respective sub collection `img`) for each image and it is not what I want:

[image]

What I want is for each document to be generated within the sub collection `img`:
[image]

I understand that the function `guardarImagen()` is iterated by each image but I do not understand how to separate it so that it generates a single document in the first level (in the second it would be the sub collection, there if iterated and it is fine) I do not know if I let myself be understood.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { FileItem } from '../class/file-item';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CargaImagenesService {

  private myFolder = 'img';

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  cargarImagenesFirebase(imagenes: FileItem[]) {

    const myTest = this.db.collection('test').ref.doc();
    console.log(myTest.id)


    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

    for (const item of imagenes) {
      item.estaSubiendo = true;
      if (item.progreso >= 100) {
        continue;
      }

      const uploadTask: firebase.storage.UploadTask =
        storageRef.child(`${this.myFolder}/${item.nombreArchivo}`)
          .put(item.archivo);

      uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        (snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) =>
          item.progreso = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100,
        (error) => console.error('Error al subir', error),
        () => {
          console.log('Imagen cargada correctamente');
          uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
            item.url = downloadURL;
            item.estaSubiendo = false;
            this.guardarImagen({
              nombre: item.nombreArchivo,
              url: item.url
            });
          });
        });
    }

  }

  
  guardarImagen( imagen: { nombre: string, url: string } ) {
    this.db.collection('test2').ref.doc().collection(`/${this.myFolder}`).add(imagen);
     
  }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem most probably comes form the line in the `guardarImagen()` function:

```
 this.db.collection('test2').ref.doc().collection(`/${this.myFolder}`).add(imagen);
```

and the fact that you do `doc()`:

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc), the `doc()` method "gets a DocumentReference for the document within the collection at the specified path. **If no path is specified, an automatically-generated unique ID will be used** for the returned DocumentReference."

You should do something like:

```
this.db.collection('test2').ref.doc('myDoc1').collection(`/${this.myFolder}`).add(imagen);
```

i.e. specify the doc to which you want to populate the sub-collection, instead of having a new doc created each time you call the function (with the automatically-generated unique ID generated by calling `doc()` without any path)

//***Edited as per Tim Martens' answer and comment***, mentioning that "adding the `.ref` converts it to the native `firebase.firestore.CollectionReference`"

Comment: I agree but as a replacement `myDoc1` to be an automatically generated ID or in any case to be a different document every time I upload images?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: How do I make `myDoc1` then be `myDoc2`, `myDoc3` and so on. Or in any case a different ID?

Comment: I think you should use the myTest doc you create at the top. I understand you get a set of images that you want to store within a sub-collection under a doc. So first create the doc (using `doc()` in this case), then iterate over the images to populate the sub-collection.

Comment: Exact! It is just what I try to do, if you have any reference or example it would be great, I support your help.

Comment: I suggest you try writing some code on the base of my answer. You are not far from it. Just create a DocumentReference with `docRef = this.db.collection('test').doc();`and use this reference to add the images by doing `docRef.collection('/${this.myFolder}').add(imagen);` in your loop.

Comment: I'm trying the following: `guardarImagen( imagen: { nombre: string, url: string } ) {
    const docRef = this.db.collection('test3').ref.doc();
    docRef.collection(`/${this.myFolder}`).add(imagen);
  }` and what generates me are different documents, each one with its respective sub collection

Comment: If I use: `const docRef = this.db.collection('test3').doc();` it generates an error `[ts] 1 argument was expected, but 0 was obtained.`

Comment: The latest (i.e. doc()  without argument) should work, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document

Comment: Maybe this is a limitation of angularfire2. I cannot help you on this framework.

Comment: I'm using `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11"` Then it is likely that this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments in Renaud's answer:
`const docRef = this.db.collection('test3').doc();`: here, the `.ref` is missing like so:
 `const docRef = this.db.collection('test3').ref.doc();`

You need to pass this `documentReference` to your `guardarImagen()` function:

```
cargarImagenesFirebase() {

    const imagenes = [
        { nombre: 1, url: 'https://url1/1.png' },
        { nombre: 2, url: 'https://url2/2.png' },
        { nombre: 3, url: 'https://url3/3.png' }
    ];

    const testDocRef = this.db.collection('test').ref.doc();

    for (const item of imagenes) {
        this.guardarImagen(testDocRef, item);
    }
}

guardarImagen(testDocRef: DocumentReference, item: { nombre: number; url: string; }): any {
    testDocRef.collection(this.myFolder).add(item);
}
```

I've omitted the uploading/storage part for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on the existing dicussion! I guess that adding the `.ref` is how it should be done in angularfire2, isn't it? In the "standard" JavaScript SDK we don't even have this property for a `CollectionReference` object

Comment: @RenaudTarnec adding the `.ref` conververts it to the native `firebase.firestore.CollectionReference`. So the difference is without `.ref`, `doc()` it is another function (`AngularFirestoreDocument`) which takes an argument